# CheckComboBox does not have show() method similar to the ComboBox

Tags: javafx-8, controlsfx

We have requirement to show CheckComboBox in expandable mode after click of button.

The normal ComboBox is having show() method and we need same method /functionality for CheckComboBox.

show() method is not availanble for CheckComboBox. Can you let us know if you have any trick to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer:

```
 CheckComboBoxSkin obj = (CheckComboBoxSkin)checkComboBox.getSkin();
         ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)obj.getChildren().get(0);
         combo.show();
```